# jQuery class NOT IN table

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several tables. I am allowing a user to add data points to the page if they haven't yet been used on the page.

All of the tables have a column with the class of `field`.

When I am providing them with the list of options to add, I want to ignore a specific table.

Basically, I want to loop over all `.fields` that are not in the table `#groupTable`.

```
$('.field:not(#groupTable)').each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) == parseInt(fieldID)){
        inUse = true;
    }
});
```

Is there something I am missing from my selector? With how it is currently shown, it is including results from the `#groupTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to exclude `.field` elements with an `id` of `#groupTable`.

Try excluding table elements with an `id` of `#groupTable`, then selecting the `.field` descendant element(s):

```
$('table:not(#groupTable) .field').each(function () {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing something, your selector excludes the table itself,
to exclude the columns from within it I would think your selector should be:

```
'.field:not(#groupTable .field)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/qzej8vtw/)

This is the selector: .field:not(#groupTable .field)